# Installing Windows without bootcamp on internal partition

Tags: windows, audio, bios, uefi, boot-camp

I recently bought an 2019 iMac with 1TB fusion drive. The 5400 rpm hard disk was too slow so what I did was unmerge the internal ssd from the internal hdd and fuse it with an external thunderbolt sdd (using CoreStorage commands). Now I have 250GB of fusion ssd drives and macOS works like a charm. The problem comes here: if I want to install windows, I can not use bootcamp beacause the assistant detects my external ssd and refuses to install windows.

After many many search I manually installed windows on a 300GB partition inside the internal HDD drive (because I want my windows to be in the HDD) using an external usb to install windows "normally". Okay so I found a solution to my first problem -> installed windows without bootcamp. But now here comes ANOTHER problem: the Windows installation was done with UEFI mode so (as I read in another posts) AUDIO does not work on Windows (even installing BootCamp drivers).

Can someone please help me with this? I'm trying to install windows using BIOS Legacy mode but my mac doesn't let me boot that way into the installer. Is there another way for doing what i'm trying to?

Comment: UEFI and Legacy are very different from eachother. If the install media does not support both, you can't boot from the install media. I doubt that UEFI secure boot is the cause for your audio not working though.

Comment: FYI: Apple eliminated BIOS booting of Macs starting in 2015. In other words, your Mac does not have a BIOS. You can only UEFI boot Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. The audio drivers downloaded by BootCamp weren’t the correct ones. I downloaded the codecs manually from Cirrus website and after installing them everything is working fine.